# How to remove the child inside movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a MovieClip on stage named scenePage, and a MovieClip named char_panel which consists of character MCs. One of these is the char1_mc.

When I clicked on char1_mc, this create a new instance(newChar), adding a child in scenePage. I also have a button named btn_remove on stage that should removes the newChar on scenePage when clicked. The problem is, the child(newChar) inside the scenePage does not removes when I clicked the button.

I tried using

```
scenePage.removeChild(newChar);
```

But it gives me an error saying, "Parameter child must non-null." Is there any other way to access the instance inside the scenePage? I really need to have access on the child on scenePage.

Here's the script inside char_panel where the char1_mc is, character1 is the class name of char1_mc after I exported it for AS3:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var newChar: MovieClip;

char1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showChar1);
function showChar1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    newChar = new character1();
    newChar.height = 215;
    newChar.width = 220;
    newChar.x = 20;
    newChar.y = 202.60;
    MovieClip(root).scenePage.addChild(newChar);
}
```

And this is the script for btn_remove which is in the main timeline.

```
btn_remove.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, remove_character);
function remove_character(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    scenePage.removeChild(newChar);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll have to show all the relevant code.   The error means there is no object assigned to the `newChar` var (or the `newChar` var doesn't exist yet/anymore)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis , I already added the script. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is one of *scope*.

The main timeline and your `char_panel` have different scopes.  This means vars in one are not available in the other.

To get to `newChar` from the main timeline, you'll have to drill down to the appropriate scope.

Let's assume `char_panel` is the instance name of an object on the main timeline.  If so, you'd have to do this on your main timeline code:

```
scenePage.removeChild(char_panel.newChar);
```

Which is saying "remove the `newChar` object that is part of the `char_panel` scope"

Comment: It works! Thank you very much @BadFeelingAboutThis!! :)